# Postgres function with text array and select where in query

Tags: arrays, postgresql, where-clause, plpgsql

I need to create a function like this (scaled down to a minimum) where I send an array of strings that should be matched. But I cant make the query to work.

```
create or replace function bar(x text[]) returns table (c bigint) language plpgsql as $$
begin
    return query select count(1) as counter from my_table where my_field in (x);
end;$$;
```

and call it like this

```
select * from bar(ARRAY ['a','b']);
```

I could try to let the parameter x be a single text string and then use something like

```
return query execute 'select ... where myfield in ('||x||')';
```

So how would I make it work with the parameter as an array?
would that be better or worse compared to let the parameter be a string?

Comment: Seems it was easy to fix the syntax when using the array by replacing x with    array_to_string(x,',')

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an array is the *cleaner* form. String matching invites corner cases where the separator is part of the string.

To find strings that match *any* of the given patterns, use the [**`ANY`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) construct:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bar(x text[])
  RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT count(*)   -- alias wouldn't be visible outside function
FROM   my_table 
WHERE  my_field = ANY(x);
$func$;
```

`count(*)` is slightly faster than `count(1)`. Same result in this query.

Using a plain SQL function (instead of PL/pgSQL). Either has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

That's fixed with the help of `unnest` that converts an array to a set (btw, the function doesn't have to be plpgsql):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bar(x text[]) RETURNS BIGINT LANGUAGE sql AS $$
    SELECT count(1) AS counter FROM my_table 
        WHERE my_field IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(x));
$$;
```

Comment: When trying to create your function I get

ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
LINE 3:         WHERE my_field IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(x));

Comment: Did you copy-paste it exactly as it is? Just re-tried successfully. Could your real function have a different arg name for `x`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the array seems to be fixed by using

```
return query select count(1) as counter from my_table where my_field in (array_to_string(x,','));
```

The point of effiency still remains unsolved.

Comment: @bereal, unless I'm misstaken, it works, but please prove that I'm wrong.

Comment: Having two entries `'foo'` and `'bar'`, I called `select * from bar(ARRAY['foo', 'bar'])` and got `0`. Actually, `array_to_string(x, ',')` returns `'foo,bar'` for this case.